# __gnu_cxx::hash showing major performance difference when the key is a pointer? while unordered_map is fast

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I observed for a million insertion, hash_map (using __gnu_cxx::hash) took around 224 sec while unordered_map<> took only 2 sec for the same.

```
#include <ext/hash_map>

typedef hash_map<char*, std::string > hashMap;
typedef unordered_map<char*, std::string> stdMap;

hashMap hM;
int N = 1000000;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        std::string ss = std::to_string(i+1);
        char *id = new char;
        hM->insert(make_pair(id,ss));
    }
```

Also if I change char* to char or int, then hash_map also take less than 2 sec.

Comment: Are you benchmarking a debug (default) build (pointless) or a optimized build?

Comment: Its with debug build. Will optimized build have affect?

Comment: Debug builds are *slow* - they contain instrumentation to catch errors and they don't optimize the code to run as fast as possible. So yes, it has an effect. *Never* benchmark debug builds - it's pointless. C++ applications should be shipped as optimized builds and that's what you should benchmark.  Loads of standard library code relies on optimization to be enabled to perform as intended, not to mention your own code.